# Application code signing failed with the error "code object is not signed at all"

Tags: macos, qt, code-signing, mac-app-store

I developed a osx app based in Qt5.1, and tried to publish it on mac app store, I have succeeded to sign frameworks and plug-ins, but faild to sign the whole application bundle,the error infomation is "code object is not signed at all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked it out.here is the solution:

first thing you should notice is you have to copy the info.plist files of Qt Frameworks into your bundle, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637131/sign-a-framework-for-osx-10-9) is the details.

then,if you sign the frameworks like [this page](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/04/03/how-to-publish-qt-applications-in-the-mac-app-store-2/) told you, you will get the same error as mine when you sign the whole bundle, which means you cann't sign frameworks with `codesign -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Developer Name" MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework` you should add some options to the command like this`codesign --verbose --force --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Developer Name" MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework` I don't know why, but it did work.

Answer (score 16):

Try adding the --deep flag to "Other Code Signing Flags" in the code signing section of the build settings.

Comment: Me too. I am using the latest beta.

Comment: Life saver! Thanks for this answer, a decade later ><