# Mac code signing Qt app with phonon

Tags: qt, codesign, phonon

I have tried signing this app many times in many different ways. I have used the code sign utilities from the latest xcode as well as the bitrock installer. They all seem to complete the signing, except that when i try to verify with:

```
codesign -vvv my.app
```

I get:

```
--prepared:my.app/Contents/Frameworks/phonon.framework
--validated:my.app/Contents/Frameworks/phonon.framework
my.app: embedded framework contains modified or invalid version
In subcomponent: my.app/Contents/Frameworks/phonon.framework
```

It seems like just this one library won't sign. I have googled for hours and I can't figure this out one. I don't know if it's something in the signing that's not right, or something wrong with that library. Is that possible?

Comment: OS X is very picky about the exact structure of a framework. We had to adjust a lot of Qt frameworks for codesigning. Compare the content of `phonon.framework` with https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign a Framework for OSX 10.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637131/sign-a-framework-for-osx-10-9)